# open action bar overflow menu programatically in Android app

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to open android support library action bar overflow menu (the one shown with three vertical dots) programatically. I know its a silly requirement but one of my client is insisting that they want the menu option to be opened and visible when user tap on a button in an activity. 
Any pointer on how to do this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`openOptionsMenu`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29) in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this implementing your own custom `ActionProvider` Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) out, in the "Creating a custom action provider" section.

Hope it helps